# Django syncdb doesn't work after invoking inspectdb

Tags: django, django-models, django-syncdb

I created a model from an existing PostgreSql database using inspectdb, when I try to do a syncdb,in order to generate the authorization tables, it generates the following error:

```
CommandError: One or more models did not validate:
db.t1: "ip": CharFields require a "max_length" attribute that is a positive integer.
```

So I put the `max_length=255` to all CharFields but it doesn't work neither with that. Django version is 1.5.1.
Anyone have an idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently `inspectdb` doesn't set `max_length` for PostgreSQL char fields without specified length. FYI, quote from postgreSQL docs:

> The notations varchar(n) and char(n) are aliases for character
>   varying(n) and character(n), respectively. character without length
>   specifier is equivalent to character(1). If character varying is used
>   without length specifier, the type accepts strings of any size. The
>   latter is a PostgreSQL extension.

But, Django [doesn't allow](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/management/validation.py#L74) to define CharFields without `max_length` parameter. There is an [open ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/14094) for it.

This django [snippet](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2328/) provides a custom `CharField` without length limit - should pass all django's validation.

Also, switching to `TextField` could help too.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I copied the exported models.py to the wrong folder, took about 2 hours to realize it. Though, thanks for your help :)

Comment: Sure, ask when you need another interesting fairy tale :)